TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in constructor
public baseUrl: string;
public exercises: Exercise[];

constructor(public http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string, ) {

  this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
  this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'api/Exercises').subscribe(result => {
      this.exercises = result.json() as Exercise[];
      console.log(this.exercises.length);//this works(returns nr of objects)
  }, error => console.error(error));

  console.log(this.exercises.length);//this doesn't work(TypeError: Cannot 
  //read property 'length' of undefined)
}

For some reason I can only get the length at the place where I assign it or in another method (triggered by some event) after the constructor is finished, so I assume the global variable is assigned after the constructor is done. Why is this the case? Is there any way to get the length inside the constructor after the get?

Because the first A in AJAX means "Asynchronous". You can't expect the result of an asynchronous call to be available immediately. If it was the case, the call would be synchonous, and you wouldn't have to subscribe to an observable using a callback function to get it. htt.get() would simply return it directly.

You can't ask someone to send you an email and then start reading the email immediately after. You can only do that when your mail client tells you that the mail has arrived.

ah, sad :( do you happen to know if there is any automatic event after the constructor is done in typescript that I can use to run some more code?

The callback you pass to subscribe() is executed when the exercises are available. That's where you should run some more code.
